# How would I encrypt my php files so only a person with a key could access them?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've done a project for a client and as part of the deal since they couldn't afford much we agreed that I own the code. however the server is in their name and they could go and steal the code. How would I avoid that? I would like only apache and me to be able to read the files!
Any alternative solutions will be appreciated!

Comment: There is no way to make your code accessible to the server (i.e. to Apache) without also making it accessible to the person/people who control the server. The best you can do is make it difficult, but not impossible, for them to read and interpret your code - that would be obfuscation.

Comment: rewrite your code in a compiled language.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of code obfuscators out there.

- http://www.raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/
- http://www.codeeclipse.com/
- http://pobs.mywalhalla.net/

Google for more.

Comment: raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/ doesn't seem to work well (php5 classes)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just host it for them?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/07/15/protecting-your-php-code/) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ioncube.com/ is pretty good and very difficult to reverse engineer. You can do single script conversions (for important functions, so if they deleted the file it'd break the site)

Answer (score -1):

I am of the opinion that you write in your contract that you own the code and they cannot edit it in any way.  The downside of course is, then you have to make all the changes, and you are on the hook if they go out of business because of you.  But in addition to other suggestions and answers, I think you should make sure the contract stipulates what you want.

Comment: I can accept being wrong, and I can accept not being optimal.  But all I did was add to the other suggestions.  Why the downvotes?

Comment: +1 agreed. The contract must state it, but people cheat all the time.

Comment: @Byron: people cheat, but the threat of a lawsuit they HAVE to defend, win or lose, might not make it worthwhile.